# ERD and flowchart editors

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, editing

I'm looking for a ERD (entity relationship diagram) editor for tablets and also a flowchart diagram... Haven't found any till now...

Does anybody knows some good app for that?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about ERD -- but there some (flowchart) diagram editors around:

- [AndyUML](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yeradis.android.yuml) can create and share simple UML diagrams. It's not "drawing", you rather "write the code", like with [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)
- [Dianoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.dianoid.lite) can *Create diagrams, uml-like flowcharts, mind-maps and sketches quickly and easily.*
- [DroidDia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarex.gred) describes itself as *similar as Microsoft Visio, but for Android tablets and phones.*
- [Smart Diagram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sillycube.android.DiagramMaker.core) says: *Usage: Flow Chart, Tree Diagram, Mind Map, etc*

There might be some more -- but this should get you started.

Some screenshots: Dianoid (left), AndyUML (right).

[image: Dianoid] [image: AndyUML]